# How to reference multiple libs with same functions and switch between them inline in Go

Tags: pointers, go, libraries

I am wondering how I can do something similar to this. I currently have multiple packages with that same structure and functions but they actually retrieve values from multiple APIs. I am also loading in a config that has an array with parameters to use one of those packages per array item. 
I am wondering how I can create a variable that uses one of those packages based on the config value. Hopefully this is clear enough. Here is pseudo code that I have written up to explain. Thanks in advance

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "flag"
    "os"
    "project/lib"
    "project/morelib"
    "project/extralib"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func stuff(info RunInfo) (err error) {

    apiKey:= "stuff1" // actually in the config
    apiSecret := "stuff2" // actually in the config
    variable := lib.New(apiKey, apiSecret) //returns *Lib struct 
    //this is where I have to comment out the other libs and uncomment them as needed
    // variable := morelib.New(apiKey, apiSecret)
    // variable := extralib.New(apiKey, apiSecret)

//trying to switch between libraries like this or in a switch statement
    if info.libname == "lib"{
        variable = lib.New(apiKey, apiSecret) //.New("", "") returns *Lib struct
    }else if info.libname == "morelib"{
        variable = morelib.New(apiKey, apiSecret) //.New("", "") returns *MoreLib struct
    }else if info.libname == "extralib"{
        variable = extralib.New(apiKey, apiSecret) //.New("", "") returns *ExtraLib struct
    }else{
        err = errors.New("there was an error with the value.....")
        return err
    }

    mystuffs, err := variable.GetBalance("USD")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("mystuff value: %v", mystuffs.value)

    return 

}
type RunInfo struct{
    libname string
    //other stuff
}
func main() {
    //load from config with array 
    config := config.Load()
    for i:=0; i<compare; i++{
        var runInfo RunInfo
        runInfo.libname = config.libname
        stuff(runInfo)
    }
}
```

pseudo lib code:

```
func New(apiKey, apiSecret string) *Lib {
client := NewClient(apiKey, apiSecret)
return &Lib{client}
}
func NewClient(apiKey, apiSecret string) (c *client) {
    return &client{apiKey, apiSecret, &http.Client{}, false}
}
type Lib struct {
    client *client
}
type client struct {
    apiKey     string
    apiSecret  string
    httpClient *http.Client
    debug      bool
}

func (b *Lib) GetBalance(currency string) (balance Balance, err error) {
    payload, err := json.Marshal(BalanceParams{Currency: currency})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    r, err := b.client.do("POST", "GetBalance", string(payload), true)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    var response jsonResponse
    if err = json.Unmarshal(r, &response); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if err = handleErr(response); err != nil {
        return
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(response.Result, &balance)

    return
}
```

Comment: Use an interface and distinct types, rather than if statements.

Comment: This is pseudo code.. not actual code. I am just looking for a way to accomplish this hypothetically based on a similar structure.

Comment: And the best way to accomplish that hypothetically, in my opinion, is to [use interfaces](https://blog.deprogramandis.co.uk/2013/03/20/if-statements-considered-harmful-or-gotos-evil-twin-or-how-to-achieve-coding-happiness-using-null-objects/).

Comment: Thank you to Emil and Cerise for your time and examples. They pointed me in the right direction and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use and if statement as in the question, a switch statement or a map.

I assume that the type returned by the `New` function is the following interface:

```
type GetStuffer interface 
    GetStuff(string) (Stuff, error)
}
```

The switch statement is:

```
var variable GetStuffer
switch info.CompareVal {
case "lib":
    variable = lib.New(string1, string2) 
case "morelib":
    variable = morelib.New(string1, string2)
case "extralib":
    variable = extralib.New(string1, string2)
default:
     return errors.New("there was an error with the value.....")
}

mystuffs, err := variable.GetMyStuff()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

For the map, initialize a package level variable with the map:

```
var m = map[string]func(string,string) GetStuffer {
   "lib": lib.New,
   "morelib": morelib.New,
   "extralib": extralib.New,
}
```

and use it like this:

```
fn := m[info.CompareValue]
if m == nil {
     return errors.New("there was an error with the value.....")
}
variable := fn(string1, string2)
mystuffs, err := variable.GetMyStuff()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

If the assumption above about the return type is not correct, then there are two options.  The first and likely the simplest is to modify `New` functions to return type `GetStuffer`.  If that's not possible, then write little adaptor functions:

```
 var m = map[string]func(string,string) GetStuffer {
   "lib":func(s1, s2 string) GetStuffer { return lib.New(s1, s2) }
   "morelib":func(s1, s2 string) GetStuffer { return morelib.New(s1, s2) }
   "extralib":func(s1, s2 string) GetStuffer { return extralib.New(s1, s2) }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question.. This does seem very close to what I am trying to get to.. however the map does not allow me to initialize the actual pointer that gets returned from that lib.New("","") func.. maybe I am not following correctly though

Comment: I am getting an error message saying "cannot use lib.New (type func(string, string) *lib.Lib ) as type func(string, string) <T> in map value. I am not sure why this could be..

Comment: I made a guess at the code you have not shown. Show the types of the New functions from a couple of packages.

Comment: I have updated the question with more pseudo code to clarify further.. thanks a lot for your help... basically I have multiple libs that connect to multiple different api's based on config values but need to switch between the libs without having to comment out the 'variable' lines for each lib, each time I want to use a different connection. They all have the same functions with a return that has the same base structure.

Comment: I updated answer, but not following along with all the name changes.  That's too much work.

Comment: yeah I wouldn't expect you to.. was there for more of a reference of what I am trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define an interface that's only one function? In your example would be

```
type Stuffer interface {
   GetMyStuff(string) (Stuff, error)
}
```

Then you declare your variable as type `Stuffer`.

Comment: The issue is that each lib has it's own functions (all the same naming/params in each lib) and there are multiple that I am calling later in the code also.. this is just pseudo code.